# How to infer the parameters of a 1D gaussian distribution using PyMC?

Tags: python, pymc, inference, mcmc, probability-density

I'm pretty new to PyMC and I'm trying desperately to infer the parameters of an underlying gaussian distribution that best fits a distribution of observed data that I have, not with a pre-build normal distrubution, but with a more general method using histograms of the simulated data to build pdfs. But so far I can't get my code to converge, and I don't know why...

So here's a summary of what my code does.

I have a dataset of 5000 points distributed normally (mean=5,sigma=2). I want to retrieve these values (mean, sigma) with a bayesian inference (using MCMC).

I have a data simulator that generates for each iteration of the MCMC process a normal distribution of 5000 points with a random mean and sigma (uniform prior)
From the simulated distribution of points I compute a numpy histogram normed to 1 representing the pdf of the distribution (Nbins=int(sqrt(5000))). I then compute the mean and standard deviation of this distribution.
What I want is the set of parameters that will allow me to build a simulated distribution that best fits the observed data.

I use the most general definition of the log likelihood, that is:

ln L(θ|x)=∑ln(f(xi|θ)) (the likelihood function being defined as the probability distribution of the observed data given the parameters θ)

Then I interpolate linearly the histogram values for every bin center. Therefore I have a continuous pdf for the simulated distribution. So here f is the interpolated function I made from the histogram of the simulation.
I sum the log(f(xi)) contributions for every (real) data point and return the loglikelihood value at the end.

But some (real) data points are so far off the mean of the simulated distribution that f(xi)=0. For these points the code raises a math domain error (Reminder: log(0)=-inf). So I artificially set the pdf to a small epsilon for the points where it's usually set to 0.

But here's the thing. The loglikelihood is not computed for every iteration. And actually it is not computed at all, in the present architecture of my code. So that's why the MCMC process is not converging. But... I don't know why.

Turns out that building custom likelihood functions does not seem to be very casual approach in the PyMC community, where people usually prefer to used pre-built distributions. I'm having troubles to find some help on these matters, so ideas and suggestions will be deeply appreciated :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import pymc as pm
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

# Generate the data
np.random.seed(0)
N=5000
true_mean=5.
true_sigma = 2.
data = np.random.normal(true_mean,true_sigma,N) 

#prior
m=pm.Uniform('m', lower=4, upper=6)
s=pm.Uniform('s', lower=1, upper=3)

@pm.deterministic 
def data_simulator(mean_input=m,sig_input=s):
    out=np.empty(4,dtype=object)
    datasim = np.random.normal(mean_input,sig_input,N)
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(datasim, bins=int(math.sqrt(len(datasim))), density=True)
    bin_centers = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])/2
    m_sim=np.mean(datasim)
    s_sim=np.std(datasim)
    out[0]=m_sim
    out[1]=s_sim
    out[2]=bin_centers
    out[3]=hist
    return out

@pm.stochastic(observed=True)
def logp(value=data,mean_output=data_simulator.value[0],sigma_output=data_simulator.value[1],bin_centers_sim=data_simulator.value[2],hist_sim=data_simulator.value[3]):
    interp_sim=InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(bin_centers_sim,hist_sim,k=1,ext=0) #returns the extrapolated values
    logp=np.sum(np.log(interp_sim(value)))
    print 'logp=',logp
    return logp

model = pm.Model({"mean": m,"sigma":s,"data_simulator":data_simulator,"loglikelihood":loglikelihood})

#Run the MCMC sampler
mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(iter=10000, burn=5000)

#Plot the marginals
pm.Matplot.plot(mcmc)
```

Comment: One tip: you can use `@pm.observed` for observed stochastics instead of passing the `observed` argument to the stochastic decorator.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pass an object called `loglikelihood` to the model instead of `logp`, which you have named it. You can circumvent issues like this by passing `locals()` to MCMC instead of manually passing them.

Comment: Also, no need to ever instantiate a `Model` object. You can pass variables directly to `MCMC`.

Comment: Also, looking even more closely, your likelihood is not a likelihood at all. It should have parents that are also PyMC nodes. You should not pass values of nodes as arguments to other nodes; use the node itself. It will automatically extract the `value` when you do that.